# install bonmin solver on windows

Tags: matlab, cmake, cygwin, solver, lapack

I want to install bonmin solver on windows 10 for yalmip.
I did whatever can be found on the internet but I still have problem in "make" line in cygwin for making executable bonmin file.
I will be grateful if somebody give me step by step of installation (include third parties) bonmin on windows.

I tried to install third parties include lapack and blas using CMAKE.
I built ALL_BIULD and INSTALL but I think I didn't succeed on that to because in cmd "lapack /?" or "blas /?" is not recognizable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a Question/Answer site about **practical problems**, not a collection of *guides* and *tutorials*. We won't give you are "step by step of installation (include third parties) bonmin on windows.". But we could help you in fixing a specific problem you have faced. For that you need to provide more information about the problem, including which **actual steps** you have performed and **exact error message** you got. You may also find useful [ask].

Comment: You don't show any code (i.e. makefile) or error message, so it's not possible to help you. Focus on one single question and provide enough details that we can reproduce what you were doing.